# How can I click 2 buttons simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

I work in a Call center (ticket based Support) and for me to get a ticket I need to click on 2 Buttons. the one that opens the tickets section, and the one that actually gets me a ticket. After i click on the Get_ticket class, the ticket box closes. So i need to start again to click on the "Tickets" Button, and then on Get_Ticket. Tickets button -> Get_ticket. And repeat and repeat. I want to tell Google console to help me with this. I found a way but it's not very friendly. I tried with the button.click function at a different interval but it's not working...If i put the function separately, it's working, but when I put the functions at the same time in Console, it's not working. Can you please give me an advice ? Those are the functions:

1.(click on TICKETS)

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName("_1f8o8ru7")[0];
setInterval(function(){button.click();},2000);
```

2.(Click on GET TICKET)

```
var button2 = document.getElementsByClassName("_sl2x43m")[0];
setInterval(function(){button2.click();},2500);
```

Comment: So basically you want to keep your ticket list open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second interval should be added inside the first interval. I also recommend to use `setTimeout`, instead of `setInterval`.

```
setInterval(function(){
   var button = document.getElementsByClassName("_1f8o8ru7")[0];
   button.click();
   setInterval(
       function(){
          var button2 = document.getElementsByClassName("_sl2x43m")[0];
          button2.click();
   },2500);
},2000);
```

After you figure it out, you can save your code in a js file: `my_script.js` and use Chrome extension **JS Injector** to automatically inject it in your page, without needing to use Chrome DEV Tools.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

Comment: In this workplace, i am not allowed to install anything, I work on a Chromebox :(

Comment: Updated the answer. If the error still occurs, this means the elements classes/ selectors might gave changed. This means that `button` and `button2` will be undefined, thus the error.

Comment: Ce tare, acum am vazut esti din Bucuresti :)

Comment: Thanks! Ma bucur ca te-am putut ajuta.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call first button click on click of first button call another method on given timeout 
so first time 1 button is clicked after on click of first button call another button method with 500 timeouts will be ok no need to do 2000 or 2500 timeout

Comment: it's not about the timing ... it's about the fact that when i run the 2 codes separately they're working. But when i put them both, it won't run

Comment: if you can try to group that button with css id or class you can call that class or css will it work can you please try this way!